# Sender.Gettype from multiple handles

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, sender, directcast

I have code that handles multiple events.  FYI - I use Devexpress Components.  I have two items, a Lookupedit and a GridLookupEdit, that are handled by the same code.  I am trying to do something like the following:

```
    Dim type = sender.GetType()

    Select Case DirectCast(sender, Type).Name
        Case "mgrLUE"
            log("View metrics for manager: " & mgrLUE.Properties.GetDisplayText(mgrLUE.EditValue), Me.Name)
        Case "sectLUE"
            log("View metrics for section: " & sectGLUE.Properties.GetDisplayText(sectGLUE.EditValue), Me.Name)
    End Select
```

I am getting errors at the select case line.  I cant figure out how to dynamically get the type to be able to direct cast to it.  The types will be DevExpress.XtraEditors.GridLookUpEdit and DevExpress.XtraEditors.LookUpEdit in this case.  I have tried searching for a solution, but everything I have tried is failing.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: So i figured out CTypeDynamic(sender, sender.GetType).Name will work, but is that the best way?

Comment: `Select Case type.Name`

Comment: @Mary : While your suggestion works I would recommend not using late binding as it is slower and much more error-prone than casting. While it may not make as much of a difference for this simple example since the outcome (when it doesn't work) will be similar in both cases, I think one should avoid late binding at all costs so that you don't get into the habit of using it. In addition it doesn't compile under `Option Strict`.

Comment: @VisualVincent Thank you for the warning about late binding. I would have thought I would get a red squiggly because I always keep Option Strict on but the code is squiggly free and compiles. I put the code in an Event procedure so I would have a sender.

Comment: @Mary, your usage of `type.name` compiles because it is not late bound.  The variable `type` is an instance of System.Type that exposes the inherited [Name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.name(v=vs.110).aspx) property.  However, that name is not the one assigned to the control as in the OP's usage.

Comment: @TnTinMn Thank you for pointing out what name would be exposed with the Name property. I thought the OP wanted to see what type was calling the method not the name of a control. I was expecting the name of the type. Yes?

Comment: @Mary, I refuse to step into that bear trap you set. Your usage implies that you're expecting that the OP wants to check the type's Name property vs the Control.Name property, but I refuse to definitively infer that.

Comment: @TnTinMn : _"your usage of `type.name` compiles because it is not late bound. The variable type is an instance of `System.Type` that exposes the inherited Name property."_ - I completely missed that. Good catch! || Mary: This means you didn't use late binding after all.

Answer (score 1):

Casting can't be done dynamically because its sole purpose is to let the compiler know that you expect an object to be of a certain type. This is necessary so that the compiler knows what members the object contains when you try to access it.

I should mention that VB.NET has a feature called *late binding*, which allows you to access members of a type wrapped in an `Object` by looking up if the member you're trying to access exists at runtime. Using late binding, however, ***is not*** recommended as it is very easy to make mistakes and break your code.

Now, as for your problem: Casting can be done if an object is of a certain type, or if it inherits from that type. Since I'm guessing what you're using are controls (that you've placed on your form) they all should inherit from `System.Windows.Forms.Control`, thus you can cast them to that which contains the base property `Name`:

```
Select Case DirectCast(sender, Control).Name
```